# python flask change sys.executable

Tags: python, apache

im have next file

```
#!/usr/bin/python3.5
from flask import Flask, render_template, request

import sys
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route("/")
def hello():
    return sys.executable

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run()
```

this code return `/usr/bin/python`
How i can change sys.executable to `/usr/bin/python3.5`
python3.5 is exist

Comment: run >> python3 flask_app.py ,instead of >>python flask_app.py

Comment: why?im not run python flask_app.py

Comment: im create site on VPS, and go to browser

Comment: im use this titirial https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-deploy-a-flask-application-on-an-ubuntu-vps

Comment: then make sure that the default python environment chosen for the vps is python 3.5... Or else use virtual environment in your vps to run the flask_app using python 3.5

Comment: I think you will have to set the path something like this in the beginning of the file. `sys.path.insert(0, '/home/username/public_html/cgi-bin/myenv/lib/python3.5/site-packages')`, depending upon the correct path.
But don't forget to import `sys` first.

Answer (score 0):

I'm shocked to discover this, but it turns out if this file in question (presumable "app.py") is executable, then the app with run using the python defined in your shebang rather than the python of you executing environment. Try this out:

`chmod +x app.py`